# Jquery Background Image FadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I've got a little problem. So I am making website where there is an input and if you paste the URL the background image will change. It is changing but the problem is that the backgrounds just flashes and it looks gross. I tried something with fadeIn/fadeOut, but nothing works as I expected. The other problem is when I click the button the background suddenly disappears until I paste a new URL.

```
    $('#bg-btn').click(function(){
    $('#bg-toggle').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#bg-url').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#main-bg').css('background-image', 
        'url("' + value + '")');
    }).keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 2nd problem you already use .keyup() at the end of your code

```
$('#bg-btn').click(function(){
    $('#bg-toggle').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#bg-url').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#main-bg').css('background-image', 'url("' + value + '")');
    }).keyup();   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  This one
});
```

so when you click the button the keyup event fired with empty value (with no background image) .. So you need to delete keyup(); from the end

for first problem you can use `.hide()` and `fadeOut()` .. So your code should be like this

```
$('#bg-btn').click(function(){
    $('#bg-toggle').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#bg-url').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        // you can use .hide() and fadeOut()
        $('#main-bg').hide(0).css('background-image', 'url("' + value + '")').fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

But I think it will be better to separate the code to be

```
$('#bg-url').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    // you can use .hide() and fadeOut()
    $('#main-bg').hide(0).css('background-image', 'url("' + value + '")').fadeOut(100);
});
$('#bg-btn').click(function(){
     $('#bg-toggle').slideToggle('slow');
     if($('#bg-url').val().trim() !== ''){  // if url is not empty
        $('#bg-url').keyup(); // or $('#bg-url').trigger('keyup');
     }else{ // if url empty
        console.log('No background image found');
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it's changing pretty good but fadeOut makes whole div disappear :/ but it works better than I expected :)

Comment: @JakubSzczepanik .. Yes this code will make whole div hide/fadeOut .. you can't fadeIn/fadeOut a background image separately .. If you necessary want to do that .. you need to make an image inside the div with absolute position and make it work as a background and you can easily then fadeIn/fadeOut that image .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can realise fades with Jquery animate method, playing with element's opacity property :

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$('#bg-btn').click(function(){
    $('#bg-toggle').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#bg-url').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var duration = 500; //Duration of animation in ms
        $('#main-bg').animate({
            opacity: 0;
        }, duration, function(){
            $('#main-bg').css('background-image', 'url("' + value + '")');
            $('#main-bg').animate({
                opacity: 1;
            }, duration, function(){
                // End of animation
            });
        });
    }).keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using css animations. A little more complex than javascript but the result is nice.

```js
$(function () { 
  var curVal = '';
  $('#example').on("change keyup paste", function(){
   //Check to make sure the value actually changed. Highlighting all triggers event using ctrl a 
   if ($(this).val() != curVal) {
      var ele = $('.background-image'),
        ele2 = $('.background-image-old');
      //Remove the old Classes
      ele2.removeClass('animate-background-old'); 
      ele.removeClass('animate-background');
      
      //Add the new backgrounds 
      ele2.css('backgroundImage', ele.css('backgroundImage'))
        .addClass('animate-background-old');
      ele.css('backgroundImage', 'url("' + $(this).val() + '")')
        .addClass('animate-background');
        
      //Hack to trigger animation
      ele.replaceWith(ele); 
      ele2.replaceWith(ele2); 
      curVal = $(this).val();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.body-wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.body-wrapper-content{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.background-image, .background-image-old{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.background-image-old{
  z-index: 1;
}


.animate-background{
   animation: animate-background 2s ease-in-out;
}
.animate-background-old{
   animation: animate-background 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 reverse;
}



@keyframes animate-background {
    from {opacity: 0}
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
  <div class="body-wrapper">
    <div class="background-image-old"></div>
    <div class="background-image"></div>
    <div class="body-wrapper-content">
      <input type="text" id="example" name="example" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```